# inserting an image as a blob type to database in QT C++

Tags: c++, image, qt, blob

I am trying to insert an image as a blob type to database after choosing the image from the computer. I have two buttons. One is to select the image. The other is button is to add the image to database

choose button

```
// to get an image stored in pc to a qlabel
void EducationSection::on_btnChse_clicked()
{
QString imageFile = QFileDialog ::getOpenFileName(0,"Select Image","/home/","Image Files (*.png)");

  QFileInfo info(imageFile);
  filename = info.fileName();
  QPixmap image (imageFile);
  ui->lblBkImge->setPixmap(image);
  ui->lblBkImge->show();

}
```

add button

```
void EducationSection::on_btnAdd_2_clicked()
{

    QByteArray byte;
    QFile file(filename);
    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        byte = file.readAll();
        file.close();
    }
    QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Error",filename);
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("insert into eduimage(image) values (:image)");
    query.bindValue(":image",byte);
    if(query.exec())
    {
         QMessageBox :: information(this,"Save","Data Inserted successfully", QMessageBox ::Ok);
    }
    else
    {
         QMessageBox :: critical(this,"Error","Couldn't insert data");
    }
}
```

Here filename is a local variable. And once the image is selected it's displayed in the label as required. But data is not inserting. Although I tried to fix the issue I couldn't. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How does your database schema look like?

Comment: image is stored as a medium blob type

Comment: You are only inserting the raw data, I therefore assume that the database handles the primary key generation?

Comment: yes primary key is auto incrementing

Comment: The next check that comes to my mind is to check whether `byte = file.readAll();` is actually executed? If there seems to be no data in the database, maybe the file simply can't be openend? From my perspective you should put your main logic into that `if` block and add an `else` block to handle cases where the file could not be read.

Comment: Thank You for telling that point. I inserted a message box inside if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){}. And that part is not executing. Please help me to figure this out. Thank you in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97418/discussion-between-user3279893-and-marcus-riemer).

Answer (score 3):

I've had this problem before with a MySQL database. The way I solved this is to explicitly specify that the binding type must be raw binary data.

In your case, try

```
query.bindValue(":image", byte, QSql::In | QSql::Binary);
```